# How to access the width and height of matplotlib axes

Tags: python, matplotlib, axes

Hello I am using Python 3.9 and cannot find a way to access the width and height of a matplotlib.pyplot.axes() object. I would like to pass the object to a function without having to also pass my defined width and height variables. If I do

```
panel1=plt.axes([0.1,0.1,0.5,0.5])
print(panel1)
```

I end up with

```
Axes(0.1,0.1;0.5x0.5)
```

But I have not idea how to access that 0.5x0.5 in a nice way. I've looked at the documentation, but am hopelessly lost.

I would like to be able to do

```
def function(panel1):
   width = panel1.width
   height = panel1.height
```